# what is the use of "//=" operator in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Given a base-10 integer,n, convert it to binary (base-2). Then find and print the base-10 integer denoting the maximum number of consecutive 1's in n's binary representation.

The code i saw

```
result = 0
maximum = 0

while num > 0:
  if num % 2 == 1:
    result += 1
    if result > maximum:
        maximum = result

else:
    result = 0

num //= 2

print(maximum)
```

what is the line 13 mean? 
why //= is used?

Comment: can you correct the indentation of your code so that Python code is readable and correct. For me, last else and num //= must be shifted to the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3 it is integer division with assignment. I.e. `7//3 = 2` and `6//3 == 2`

Edit:
Example:

```
a = 7
a //= 3
print(a)
```

then the output will be `2`